# Que hacer para que los datos se queden grabados en el programa con Eclipse sin tener que instalar MySQL

Tags: java

Hasta ahora he usado `MySQL` para guardar los datos localmente de mi programa en `Java` usando `Eclipse` y `WindowsBuilder`.

Pero, me gustaría saber cómo guardar los datos en el mismo programa sin necesidad de instalar `MySQL` en la computadora, dudo mucho que todos mis usuarios quieran instalar `MySQL`.

Existen millones de programas que instalas y todo lo que haces o cambias se queda guardado en el mismo programa, es decir, el programador no te dice: hey!, debes instalar `MySQL` para usar mi programa.

¿Qué opciones existen para guardar los datos en el mismo programa?.

---

Y contestando a los comentarios: He escuchado sobre `SQLite` pero, ni idea de qué es o cómo funciona.

Comment: Puesdes escribirlos y leerlos de un txt, o de un excel.

Comment: no creo que es la forma profesional que todos usan o si?, miles de programas existen que te guardan todo lo que haces en tu PC sin necesidad de que el cliente instale MySQL.

Comment: Generalmente se usan una capa de abstracción de bases de datos. Si tienes una capa de abstracción, puedes cambiar la base de datos desde MySql a SQlite sin problemas. Puedes ver este [post en ingles](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/08/13/four-types-of-database-abstraction-layers/).  El sitio de SqLite es https://sqlite.org/about.html

Comment: Ya usaste SQLite?

Comment: "*mi programa en Eclipse*" no nos da ninguna certeza del entorno en el que estás. ¿En qué lenguaje de programación? ¿para qué ambiente?

Comment: he editado mi pregunta inicial para hacerla mas clara. @Mariano

Comment: @CarlosHernández aún no, nunca había escuchado sobre él.

Answer (score 2):

Al decir Eclipse y no especificar ningún tipo de lenguaje en particular te voy a dar mi respuesta desde el punto de vista de Java que es el lenguaje de programación que seguramente uses (aunque la respuesta será la misma para todos los lenguajes):

Un programa no es más que una secuencia de código (una receta), por lo que al iniciarse correctamente enviará todas las lineas de código al procesador en un lenguaje que el entienda para que las ejecute una detrás de otra hasta llegar al final. Una vez llegado al final el sigue a lo suyo y te olvida para siempre. La posibilidad de que cuando tu en un futuro vuelvas a ejecutar el programa el recuerde algo de lo que ha pasado pasa necesariamente por que lea los datos en algún lado.

¿Existe algún lado que no sea una base de datos, en tu caso concreto MySQL, para que esos datos puedan ser amacenados allí, y que el programa una vez arranca los lea y los vaya actualizando para que siempre pueda acceder a ellos? La respuesta es clara: SI. Por supuesto que existen formas de guardar los datos que no pasan por MySQL, prueba de ello es que existen diferentes tipos de servidores de bases de datos como lo puede ser también, SQLite, etc... que guardan los datos de formas muy diferentes.

La respuesta que buscas de todas ellas más sencilla, y creo que hablo por experiencia ya que me has recordado a mi cuando empeze la carrera de Ingenieria informátiaca (¿Pero dónde guardo yo esto para que no lo olvide?), en ficheros que tu mismo te crees en algún directorio que tengas controlado de antemano (seguramente dentro de la carpeta del programa o en carpetas tipo /var o /tmp en entornos UNIX)

Guardando todo en carpetas y ficheros de forma que sepas como los datos se han guardado para que sepas como han de ser leidos obtendrás esa base de datos casera que estamos buscando. Entrando en este temá y por responder a tu pregunta con la mayor informacíon posible al respecto, la serializacion de objetos trata exactamente esto: convertir un objeto en una secuencia de bytes para poder escribir/leer sobre ellos sin problemas.

Comment: Está muy bien planteado el punto. Pero, ¿si está desarrollando en Java para Android, no te parece que habría una mejor respuesta específica en ese caso? Mi recomendación es que, en estos casos, esperes a que el autor aclare su pregunta antes de responderle.

Comment: He editado mi pregunta inicial, espero que sea mas claro y puedan ayudarme con la solución.